# Using channels outside consumers.py but function in consumers not firing

Tags: django-channels

I am trying to send a message to django consumers.py from one user to another after a user logs in. However, the chat_message function doesn't seem to be firing with the code I wrote in the log in function in views.py as "ccc" in not printing on the server side. New to Django Channels here. Would appreciate any input to this problem of mine.

consumers.py

```
class OnlineFriends(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope["user"]
        print(self.room_name)
        print(self.channel_layer)
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_' + str(self.room_name)
        print(self.room_group_name)
        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        print("aa")

        message = self.channel_name.split("-")
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'message': message
            }))

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        print("ccc")
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

users.views.py ***Updated**

```
class Login(View):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template = 'login.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form=self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template, {'form':form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    user.onlinestatus = True
                    user.save()
                    for obj in user.friends.all():
                        print( user.friends.all())
                        if obj.onlinestatus == True:                       
                            print("obj: "+ str(obj.username))
                            channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
                            print("channel_layer: "+ str(channel_layer))
                            room_name = "chat_" + str(obj.username)
                            print("room_name: "+ str(room_name))
                            print(obj.channel_name)
                            async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send(
                                room_name, {
                                "type": "chat.message",
                                "message": room_name,
                            }))
                            
                    return redirect('home')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("No such user.")
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'form':form})
```

traceback **updated**

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /friendslist/ [127.0.0.1:49751]        ****loading home page on browser****
foonghanyao                    ****output from consumers.OnlineFriends.connect****
RedisChannelLayer(hosts=[{'address': ('127.0.0.1', 6379)}])
chat_foonghanyao
WebSocket CONNECT /friendslist/ [127.0.0.1:49751]
HTTP GET /static/songs/images/favicon.png 200 [0.02, 127.0.0.1:61225]
<QuerySet [<User: foonghanyao>]>         ****output from Login class in views.py****
obj: foonghanyao
channel_layer: RedisChannelLayer(hosts=[{'address': ('127.0.0.1', 6379)}])
room_name: chat_foonghanyao
specific.45d45ec67e0a4282b2066d67847e4bab!8ab6617c8be94d0dabefadf636ba886e
HTTP POST /accounts/login/ 302 [0.88, 127.0.0.1:60752]
<QuerySet [<Tag: apple>, <Tag: bee>]> 
HTTP GET /home/ 200 [0.16, 127.0.0.1:60752]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /friendslist/ [127.0.0.1:55762]       ****Disconnecting from websockets in login page****
aa
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /friendslist/ [127.0.0.1:58978]       ****new page loading after being redirected following log in****
brandonfoong
RedisChannelLayer(hosts=[{'address': ('127.0.0.1', 6379)}])
chat_brandonfoong
WebSocket CONNECT /friendslist/ [127.0.0.1:58978]
```

sync.routing.py **updated**

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"^friendslist/$", consumers.OnlineFriends.as_asgi(), name='friendslist'),
]
```

mainapp.asgi.py **updated**

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "music.settings")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": get_asgi_application(),
  "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            sync.routing.websocket_urlpatterns,
        )
    ),
})
```

Comment: Can you explain what your desired output is and what you are getting, one thing, when using channel-layer you should also pass the object currently you are getting ```<asgiref.sync.AsyncToSync object at 0x00000207C8311B38>``` is because you printing the reference of the object into the console. Thereby use ```self.channel_layer.group_send```.

Comment: I am trying to have users send a message upon login to other associated users who have already signed in. Right now i want to have my login function in views.py to trigger the chat_message in consumers.py. Since you brought it up, may i know what's the difference between self.channel_layer.group_send and channel_layer.group_send? It's just channel_layer.group_send in the documentation where it teaches to send messages outside of consumers.py. I am getting "'Login' object has no attribute 'channel_layer'" by doing what you suggested, using CBV here.

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong. I copied your code and it works for me. I only changed `self.room_name = self.scope["user"]` to `self.room_name = self.scope["user"].username`. I'm not sure what you are doing in your views.py but `async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send(channel_name,{"type":'chat_message',"message": channel_name, }))` works fine for me. Are you sure that at the time of sending the message to group there is a user connected to `room_group_name `?

Comment: As far as I understand you want to notify one user that another user just logged in. You need to make sure that the user you want to notify is connected to the WebSocket and that you are sending a message to his room, not to the room of user who have just logged in.

Comment: I have added some extra info to my question stem. My output remains the same, with the chat.message function in comsumers not firing. Just to top off on what I am doing, i built my site in a way whereby I wrote my websockets code in the base.html hence websockets would connect and disconnect each time a new page is loaded. While testing, I am loaded my home page in one browser and logged in to the site using another browser (on another account) with the previous browser tab left open. Pretty sure I missed something very fundamental here. Do let me know if you detect anything.